# Spring-integration DSL : how to get programmatically the default channel of a integration flow?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(){
    return f->f
            .handle(m ->{System.out.println(m);throw  new RuntimeException("probleme");});

}
```

Given this flow how could I get programmatically the default channel("flow.input")?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("flow.input")
private MessageChannel flowInputChannel;
```

or

```
MessageChannel flowInputChannel = applicationContext.getBean("flow.input", MessageChannel.class);
```